# How to use regex in pfsense firewall logs (GUI)

Tags: firewall, regex, pfsense

pfSense: 2.3.2-RELEASE-p1 
 
How can I filter two ports in the firewall logs? I just can't figure it out. 
Go to Status > System Logs > Firewall > Normal view > Advanced Log Filter to try. Like on the picture, I want to filter out every IP using ports 67 and 137. But no result. I looked up in the regex doc, tried multiple combinations but nothing works. When I put one value, then there is no problem.

[image]

**UPDATE**

This resolved my problem. I had to remove the spaces.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from pfSense forum:

Remove the spaces.
What that is actually filtering on is "67 "|" 137"

Credits to NOYB

Answer (score 1):

You may want to include an exact match, This should do it (^67$|^137$).

See this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#105924

Comment: Are you sure that pfSense supports PCRE regex? Why do you give a link to PHP?

Comment: I used this particular regex, with different ports, just before I posting, as the one from maxium did not work, or portion of it would not provide any port with the number in it (i.e. 2067 and 85137), rather than precise port.